Is there way to display historical records for all model instances using django-simple-history?
I am using django-simple-history for saving history of the objects. And it works fine. But I want to create a view in django admin that displays history records for all instances in model in one page.
For example I have a model
class TestModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=100)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

and admin
class TestModelAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):
    list_display = ['title']
admin.site.register(TestModel, TestModelAdmin)

And now I can see the history of each instance.
Not sure how I can solve this problem. May be there is a way to create custom views in admin site (without model), or maybe I should create another model?
What's the best way to display all history records (for all instances) in admin panel?

Use the through model of the TestModel.history as admin model:
class HistoricalTestModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'history_object']


admin.site.register(TestModel.history.model, HistoricalTestModelAdmin)
The .history_object refers to the object for which we track the history. So in this case we can for example find the historical titles of your TestModel objects.

Thank you. It is exactly what I needed
